# difference vs using and not using complete callback function

Tags: jquery

I was hanging a lot on my code but corrected after a few hours of work and surprised about the difference.

Why my first code only works for first time only not after the first click but works great with second code?

[without using complete function](http://jsfiddle.net/3e9Y6/2/):

```
$('button').click(function(){
    $('.f').fadeToggle(400);
    if($('.one').is(':visible')){
        $('.apps').text("one apps");
    }
    if($('.two').is(':visible')){
        $('.apps').text("two apps");
    }
});
```

[by using complete function](http://jsfiddle.net/3e9Y6/1/):

```
$('button').click(function(){
    $('.f').fadeToggle(400,function(){

        if($('.one').is(':visible')){
            $('.apps').text("one apps");
        }
        if($('.two').is(':visible')){
            $('.apps').text("two apps");
        }

    });

});
```

Can anyone please give me the proper description why it's not working with first code?

Comment: What is your item with the `description` class? It is not in your fiddle

Comment: thanks, that was copy paste mistake, corrected.

Comment: for me both versions seem to work absolutely the same ... on mac osx and latest stable chrome

Comment: Same here: working the same for both versions

Comment: okay theres a difference sorry

Comment: because in second you are using callback. and callback wait for fade in to complete before changing text of div. but first one don't wait.

Comment: but should change the text after every click, no?

Answer (score 0):

The documentation of [`.fadeToggle`](https://api.jquery.com/fadeToggle/) tells us that this function accepts three parameters:

```
.fadeToggle( [duration ] [, easing ] [, complete ] )
```

or one parameter:

```
.fadeToggle( options )
```

You are using the first form. In it the last parameter is

> A function to call once the animation is complete.

So you must wrap everything you want to do *after* the animation is completed inside a function. That's what you do in your second code sample.

Your first code sample does not execute *anything* after the animation is *completed*. The code after the call to `fadeToggle` is executed *immediately*. This is probably not what you want.

Answer (score 0):

I added a timeout to show the main problem. Here you are interfering with the `fadeToggle`: in fact, during the 400ms toggle time, your divs are not hidden: they are both visible!

You can see it with this sample:

In the HTML I added a div to display the visible states:

```
<div style="height: 25px; overflow:hidden;">
<div class="one f">one</div>
<div class="two f">two</div>
</div>
<div class="apps"></div>
<button>click me</button>

<div id="checkVisible"></div>
```

And in the javascript, I used setTimeout to check things during the transition (here with a value of 300), but also to check after (with a value of 500 for example) and you will se the difference.

```
$('button').click(function(){
    $('.f').fadeToggle(400);

    setTimeout(function() {
        var oneVisible = $('.one').is(':visible');
        var twoVisible = $('.two').is(':visible');
        $("#checkVisible").text(oneVisible + " / " + twoVisible);

        if(oneVisible){
            $('.apps').text("one apps");
        }
        if($('.two').is(':visible')) {
            $('.apps').text("two apps");
        }
    }, 300);

});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/nrobert/3e9Y6/6/

- With 300, you will have both item "visible", that's why your code is not working.
- With 500, you will have 1 visible and 1 not visible, like when you did it with "complete"

You should update update your text on toggle complete, or with an other check, you cannot use visible during this transition.

Comment: I just explained `the proper description why it's not working with first code?` as you questionned. the SetTimeout is not a solution!
The solution is to use the complete function like you did